# Why is "comprehensive knowledge"?

Tags: word-choice

Here is a question.

As a great programmer, Mrs.Danny has a comprehensive __ of the computer software programs.
A. ability
B. collector
C. knowledge
D. memory

I think A is correct, the answer is C.Why is "comprehensive ability" wrong?
 "Something that is comprehensive includes everything that is needed or relevant" is one of the explications of "comprehensive". So I thought it represents Mrs.Danny has the various ability on computer software programs.

Comment: "A comprehensive ability of... (something)" is not grammatical.

Comment: Normally you would have an ability to...(something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider the words which collocate with each option.

*Ability* takes a "to"-infinitive phrase (*ability to sing well*) or (rarely) "for" with a noun phrase (*an ability for original thinking*). It doesn't take *of*.

*Collector* certainly takes *of* (*a collector of programs*), but it is not a property but a description of a person, so it would match *is*, but not *has*.

*Knowledge* and *memory* both take *of*. Syntactically, *memory* would fit, but it makes much less sense than *knowledge*.

Note, by the way, that the question as you have written it is not idiomatic in English. First, unless specific programs are being referred to (unlikely in the context) there should not be a *the* in it. Secondly, any two of *computer*, *software*, and *programs* would be fine, but the three are not normally all used together.